# Problemas com apostrofós utilizando Phpspreadsheet para escrever xlsx

Tags: php, xls, phpexcel

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu preencho uma planilha com as informações de uma pessoa, entretanto, nomes como D'anna geram um problema no xlsx.
O D'anna fica com um quadrado no lugar do apostrofo '. 
a forma de escrita que eu utilizo é essa:

```
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($this->planilha, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

e na hora de setar o valor na célula, eu utilizo:

```
planilha->setCellValue(utf8_encode($value['nome']);
```

Para os outros valores, funciona corretamente, só para o apostrofo que gera problema.
Alguem pode me ajudar?
grato!

Comment: Não sei se vai adiantar muita coisa, mas poderia tentar algo assim: `planilha->setCellValue(utf8_encode("$value['nome']");`

Comment: Isso gera um erro de sintaxe, devido a variável.
Agradeço mesmo assim!

Comment: Pena! O PHPSpreadsheet tem mesmo problema com  as aspas simples.